# How to pass prop of a child to another child? (React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I need to pass a prop (it's a unique id) from one child component to another, but I can't do it.

The operation is simple: Homepage is the parent and has two direct children: Gallery and Detail. Gallery using a map prints its children Cards, which have a unique id. I need that when clicking on a card button, that unique id can be received by Detail.

I tried to manage it through handleClick but since I already manage a state there, I don't know if it is possible to manage it from there or are other methods.

This is the code:

```
interface DetailProps {}

const Detail: React.FC<DetailProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span className="tituloJuego">DENTRO DE DETAIL</span>
    </div>
  );
};

interface CardProps {
  id: number;
  image: string;
  title: string;
  price: string;
  onClick: (result: string) => void;
}

const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img className="image" src={props.image} />

      <div className="card-info">
        <div className="containerTitlePrice">
          <span className="tituloJuego">{props.title}</span>
          <br></br>
          <span className="-USD">{props.price}</span>
        </div>

        <div className="containerButton">
          <button className="Rectangle" onClick={(event) => props.onClick("detail")}>
            <span className="Install-Game">BUY NOW</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

interface GalleryProps {
  onClick: (result: string) => void;
}

const Gallery: React.FC<GalleryProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    // Se recorren los datos de json con map y se imprime cada card
    <div className="container">
      {data.map((games, key) => {
        return (
          <Card
            id={games.id}
            image={games.image}
            title={games.title}
            price={games.price}
            onClick={(event) => props.onClick("detail")}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const Homepage: React.FC = () => {
  // Por defecto el estado muestra homepage
  const [currentView, setCurrentView] = React.useState<string>("homepage");
  const handleClick = () => setCurrentView("detail");

  const [currentClickedGame, setCurrentClickedGame] = React.useState<number>(0);

  return (
    <div className="Simplified-homepage">
      {currentView === "homepage" ? (
        <div className="store-gallery">
          <Gallery onClick={handleClick} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="">
          <Detail />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(<Homepage />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the json file. The data from this file is the data that im showing in the Cards. The "ID" is the number that I want to pass from Card to Homepage:

[JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCh27.png)

Comment: Would you mind if you could make a sandbox where you can show full code. If you like you can use https://codesandbox.io/ . This will make easier to understand what exactly is the problem.

Comment: There is no more code more than a json (id, title, name, ...). Im new in React and I have difficulties to understand how to pass the ID from the component Card to the component father Homepage. Thanks!

Comment: Please add JSON also...

Comment: Done! Every item of the JSON has an ID, title, url, price and description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the state `currentClickedGame` in both the child components for handling the `ID`.
You can't pass props on components in the same level or from child to parent as react follows unidirectional data flow .Also, instead of passing the `handleClick` from Homepage you can manage it inside Card component itself and set `setCurrentView` from there.
I've drilled props to 2 levels, consider using [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in a more complex case

In `HomePage`:

```
return (
    <div className="Simplified-homepage">
      {currentView === "homepage" ? (
        <div className="store-gallery">
          <Gallery setCurrentClickedGame ={setCurrentClickedGame}/>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="">
          <Detail currentClickedGame={currentClickedGame}/>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

And in Gallery component:

```
   return (
          <div key={games.id}>
            <Card
              id={games.id}
              image={games.image}
              title={games.title}
              price={games.price}
              setCurrentView={props.setCurrentView}
              setCurrentClickedGame={props.setCurrentClickedGame}
            />
          </div>
        );
```

[View demo on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-rain-4943w?file=/src/index.tsx:2576-2925)

Comment: Thank you very much! I understant your code but now I have a little problem: How does the Gallery interface have to be now? For example if I wrote "setSelectedId: number;" in the interface, i got an error in "props.setCurrentClickedGame(games.id) "

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand how I can manage handleClick inside Gallery. if I do that, in Homepage I get an error in "currentView === "homepage" because currentView is in Gallery, not in Homepage. Can you write the rest of the code? Thank you very much, I really want to understand all of this.

Comment: @Marcus I've slightly refactored the code, Please check the codesandbox link in the answer.

Comment: Now I can understand everything. Works perfectly, thank you very much!